# Error: Chaincode already installed - Composer-playground

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I ran [composer-playground](https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net) and went to `deploy a new business network`. I wanted to upload and deploy my already created `.bna` file. But when I do the same and click deploy, it gives me following error:

> Error: Chaincode already installed: my-business-network@0.0.2-deploy.2

The playground version is - Playground v0.19.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since composer-playground save all data in browser, so clear browser history would solve the problem.

Comment: I had to clear my browser history as well as the composer-playground cookies in order to get rid of the error. As the website data was getting stored in the cookies! Thanks for the direction though!

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, in the current version of playground(Playground v0.19.0), there is an option of `Update Network` just above `Deploy changes`. If we just change name of `To` deploying network (or even just change the last deploy-build digit) and then `Deploy changes`, it works.